# How to pass parameters with the action Helper of Ember.js inside an input field from an Handlebars template?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

In my handlebars template I have this loop:

```
{{#each itemController="fund"}}
    <li>                        
        <label>{{title}}</label>            
        <span>{{amount}}</span>
        {{input type="text" placeholder="new user"
        value=newFullName action="createUser"}}
        {{partial 'user-list'}}
    </li>
{{/each}}
```

and need to pass the current object as parameter to the 'createUser' action.
Something like this:

```
action="createUser(this)"
```

or:

```
action 'createUser' this
```

But it seems that ember can't handle parameters for actions inside an input field...

Am i missing something?

Comment: How your "action" will be executed then? Usually you must provide something like event="click" or another way to invoke that action.

Comment: The default is that the action is invoked on enter.

Comment: I'm stuck with a similar problem! Ember tutorial (https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/tutorial/autocomplete-component/) has  {{input value=filter key-up=(action 'autoComplete' filter)}} which does not  work, firing "An action named 'autoComplete' was not found in (generated index controller)".

Comment: This is now possible - see my answer below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that isn't possible to do this using the `action` property from `input` view helper.

A workaround could be wrap your input in a form that use the `action` view helper using the submit event, like the following:

Template

```
{{#each}}
      <li>                   
          <form {{action "createUser" this on="submit"}}>
              {{name}}
              {{input type="text" value=name}}          
          </form>
      </li>
  {{/each}}
```

Route

```
  ...
  actions: {
    createUser: function(user) {
      alert(user.get('name'));
    }
  }
  ...
```

So when the user hit enter, will have the event triggered.

The main difference between the action property and the action view helper is that the action view helper is more flexible and you can supply the context and put it inside of any tag:

```
<div {{action "someAction" someObject}} on="click">Click me</div>
```

In the route:

```
actions: {
  someAction: function(someObject) {
    // do something with the someObject
  }
}
```

See the [docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_action) for further information

Please give a look in the jsfiddle to see that sample in action http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/UAgjX/

I hope it helps

Comment: move brackets in <div {{action "someAction" someObject}} on="click">Click me</div>

Comment: Is there a solution for <input type="file" /> to pass onchange event in action helper and access "files" property?

Answer (score 10):

You can now pass a function, along with values -

```
submit=(action 'setName' 'Sal')
```

http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/12/ember-1-13-0-released.html#toc_closure-actions

Comment: Yeah this works. Surprised they haven't put it in the guides yet

Comment: Now this should be acceptable answer for newer versions

Answer (score 2):

Finally i ended up with this solution:

Template

```
{{input class="newUser" type="text" value=newFullName placeholder="add user"}}
<button {{action 'createUser' this newFullName}}>Send</button>
```

Controller

```
createUser: function (fund, newFullName) {
        var fullName = newFullName;                        
        var user = this.store.createRecord('appUser', {
            fullName: fullName,                
            fund: fund,
            payments:[]
        });
        user.save().then(function(){                
            fund.get('users').pushObject(user);                
            fund.save().then(function(){
                fund.reload();
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: why use this? Why not just do a get("newFullName") in the action handler?

Answer (score -3):

You can pass a parameter to an action helper :`{{action "doSomething" xxx }}`

Where doSomething is your controller method ,and xxx is anything in the current context of the template.